# Build dictionary from string containing key=value

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.6

I am trying to build a dictionary from a string like this:

```
paramString = (dtoxe_n_18_cdmos=0.0000e+000, dxl_n_18_cdmos=0.0000e+000, du0_n_18_cdmos=0.0000e+000, dvth0_n_18_cdmos=0.0000e+000)
```

I used

```
paramDict = dict(paramString)
```

but it Returns the error "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"
Are perhaps the underscores in the key a Problem? Because as far as I can tell, according to [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) it should be the correct Notation.

Thanks guys and girls!

Comment: oops, Version 2.4.1.0, sorry!

Comment: Do you have any specific reason to use this archaic version?

Comment: ah ok sorry again, I am using PyScripter Version 2.4.1.0, not sure where I can check the Python Version it's using?
You guys are fast!

Comment: @moringana what does `import sys; print(sys.version)` show you?

Comment: @JonClements 2.6.6 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following dict comprehension ,:

```
>>> s="dtoxe_n_18_cdmos=0.0000e+000, dxl_n_18_cdmos=0.0000e+000, du0_n_18_cdmos=0.0000e+000, dvth0_n_18_cdmos=0.0000e+000"
>>> d={k:v for k,v in [i.split('=') for i in s.split(',')]}
>>> d
{' du0_n_18_cdmos': '0.0000e+000', ' dxl_n_18_cdmos': '0.0000e+000', 'dtoxe_n_18_cdmos': '0.0000e+000', ' dvth0_n_18_cdmos': '0.0000e+000'}
```

first you can split your string by `,` then split with `=` . you can do it with following list comprehension `[i.split('=') for i in s.split(',')]` then loop over it and choose your key and value !

if you are in python 2.4 you need to use `dict` :

```
>>> d=dict([i.split('=') for i in s.split(',')])
```

Comment: The OP (for some unfathomable reason) is using Python 2.4 - you'll have to for-go the dict-comp and rewrite using `dict`...

Comment: Okay... the OP isn't using Python 2.4 - they've confused it with the PyScripter version :)

Comment: @JonClements yep, fixed , !

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I am using PyScripter 2.4.1.0., not sure which Python Version. When I try out `d={k:v for k,v in [i.split('=') for i in s.split(',')]}
` however, i get a Syntax error

Comment: @moringana check out the edit , you need to use `dict` .

Comment: If you want values to be float, you can do it like this: `d=dict([(k,float(v)) for k,v in (i.split('=') for i in s.split(','))])`

Comment: @KasraAD yay okay the edit works :) could anybody explain to me why my Version doesn't work though?

Comment: @moringana because `dict` doesn't take a string... it takes key/value pairs...  or named parameters `dict(a=1, b=2)` is different than `dict('a=1, b=2')`...

Comment: @JonClements okay thanks Jon, I think i understand now. but there is no way to somehow get rid of the string Attribute and pass it to dict()? to my limited python knowledge that doesn't seem like it could be that hard

Comment: @moringana I believe what you're asking is shown in the answer by Sebastian which effectively builds a line of code then evaluates it... however, evaluating untrusted input is dangerous - it's generally much safer to tokenize the string and feed `dict` with key/value pairs as shown in this answer...

Answer (score 1):

A very ugly but working solution:

`parmDict = eval("dict(" + paramString + ")")`